# Time Complexity of a recursive function f(n) that calls f(n-3)

Tags: time-complexity

Here is the function I found in sample problems for my exam:

```
function(int n)
{
    if(n==1)return; 
    for(int i=1;i≤n;i++)
    {      
        for(int j=1;j≤n;j++)
        { 
          printf("∗");
          function(n−3);
        }
     } 
}
```

The solution suggests the recursive relation is
`T(n) = n^2 + T(n-3)`.

Shouldn't it be `T(n) = n^2 * T(n-3)` instead? Since ``function(n-3)`gets called`n^2` times?

Comment: You are right in your analysis.